# Why is my reason argument in my mute command using one word of the reason?

Tags: python, discord.py

My mute command is only getting one word of the reason I choose. Does anyone know why?

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_guild_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def tempmute(ctx, member: discord.Member, time, reason=None):
    muted_role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Muted")
    time_convert = {"s":1, "m":60, "h":3600,"d":86400, "w":604800, "mo":2592000, "y":31104000}
    tempmute = int(time[:-1]) * time_convert[time[-1]]
    await member.add_roles(muted_role)
    embed=discord.Embed(title=f"Member Muted", description=f"{member} has been muted for {time}.")
    embed.add_field(name=f"Moderator", value=f"{ctx.message.author}", inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name=f"Reason", value=f"{reason}", inline=True)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    await asyncio.sleep(tempmute)
    await member.remove_roles(muted_role)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [discord.py documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#why-do-my-arguments-require-quotes):

> In a simple command defined as:
>
> ```
> @bot.command()
> async def echo(ctx, message: str):
>    await ctx.send(message)
> ```
>
> Calling it via `?echo a b c` will only fetch the first argument and disregard the rest. To fix this you should either call it via `?echo "a b c"` or change the signature to have “consume rest” behaviour. Example:
>
> ```
> @bot.command()
> async def echo(ctx, *, message: str):
>    await ctx.send(message)
> ```
>
> This will allow you to use `?echo a b c` without needing the quotes.

In your case, either pass the reason surrounded in `"quotes"`, or add an `*` argument between `time` and `reason` in your command signature.

Comment: Thanks! Putting the `*` between the `time` and `reason` worked perfectly :D

Comment: Always happy to help. I've had this issue myself before :)